# Why both packages are needed in an Android project using google maps v2?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps-android-api-2

For using google maps v2 api, i imported google_play_services_lib. everything is working fine. But i wanted to know why com.google.android.maps(inside Google APIs) and com.google.android.gms.maps(inside Android Private Libraries) both packages inside library are imported as dependency while com.google.android.maps is for V1 and com.google.android.gms.maps is for V2 . I have searched a lot but .....

Comment: do you need `com.google.android.maps`? why?

Comment: i dont need but when i set dependency for google_play_services_lib , i find com.google.android.maps in a library folder(newly created) named Google APIs. @Xingchen

Comment: In `gradle.build` `dependencies`: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'`, that's all for gms

Comment: i mentioned eclipse....

Comment: In eclipse, you just need import `google-play-services_lib` as library to your project.